# Taking data files, calculating correlation

Tags: r, correlation

I am currently doing the R course on Coursera. The first homework assignment is giving me trouble. Here are the instructions:

> Write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold
>   for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and
>   nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed
>   cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function
>   should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the
>   threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement,
>   then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0.

I have been working on this for quite a while, so I am not just asking people to do my homework for me.

Here is my R code

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE) #reads a    directory of files

  cor_vector <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 0)

  for(each in 1:332) {
    tempdata <- read.csv(files_list[each])
    tempdata_complete <- complete.cases(tempdata)
    counter <- nrow(tempdata_complete)
      if(counter>threshold) {
        cor_vector <- cor(tempdata_complete[["nitrate"]], tempdata_complete[["sulfate"]])
      }
  }

  return(cor_vector)

}
```

Aside from whether it's actually doing what I want, I am getting this error

`Error in if (counter > threshold) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: Step through your code one line at a time for one file, and check that each line of code is giving your expected outcome. For example, id check `complete.cases(tempdata)`.

Comment: I think you will find that searching SO with a search term of `[r] 332` will bring up a whole boatload of worked examples. You are failing to heed the instructions of Coursera which tells you to post questions on their website.

Comment: tempdata_complete <- complete.cases(tempdata) is giving me all FALSE's.

Comment: Yes, thank you 42. I did post on their website, and I am not asking you to do my homework for me.

Comment: Since you know the problem is that `(counter > threshold)` is length 0, you can also add a statement before your `if` statment that says `if(length(counter > threshold) == 0){print(each)}`.  That will let you know what iteration you are having trouble with so you can run just that iteration and find the problem.

Comment: Well that suggets that there are no rows in your data without missing data. However, you noticed that `complete.cases(tempdata)` is a vector, so it does not have any rows (then `nrow(tempdata_complete)` will be `NULL`, and it will not have any columns so `tempdata_complete[["nitrate"]]` will throw an error. The examples`?complete.cases` show how to subset your dataframe.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, user20650.

Comment: okay, lets use the `mtcars` dataset as an example of `tempdata` and then run your code. `tempdata <- mtcars` ; Then `tempdata_complete <- complete.cases(tempdata)`. Have a look at `tempdata_complete`: it is a logical vector. Then `counter <- nrow(tempdata_complete)`. Now look at `counter`: it returns `NULL` as it doesnt have any rows. Then it wont work if you try to use any columns (`cor(tempdata_complete[["mpg"]], tempdata_complete[["wt"]])`) as, remember, `tempdata_complete` is just a logical vector (it has nor rows or columns) .

Comment: cont... So to subset your data use `tempdata_complete <- tempdata[complete.cases(tempdata), ]`

Comment: I see. Okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much!

It returns one number. I was trying to get it to return a whole vector as the requirements are:

`The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. `

Comment: okay. As you are iterating through the files, you also need to index the output vector, so use `cor_vector[each] <- cor(` (ps: it is *a lot* more efficient to pre-allocate your output vector with the expected return length (rather than length zero), so I'd use `cor_vector <- numeric(length(files_list))`) . Also, note that you currently skipping over the files that have zero non-missing rows rather than returning a numeric(0) term)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for your help, u20650. 
I am still getting NA's in the output, which I thought I eliminated through the `complete.case` statement.

`[1]          NA -0.01895754          NA -0.04389737 -0.06815956          NA`

Comment: That could be due to the first, third, sixth files not having any non-missing, so nor cor data.

Comment: Interesting. Okay, so when I put in the directory and threshold arguments
`> cr <-corr("specdata", 150)`
`> head(cr)`
`[1]          NA -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667`

However, the output I should be getting (according to coursera) is 
`cr <- corr("specdata", 150)`
`head(cr)`
`[1] -0.01896 -0.14051 -0.04390 -0.06816 -0.12351 -0.07589`

Comment: Look at my final sentence [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902999/taking-data-files-calculating-correlation#comment70990586_41902999) you are just passing over the files / indexes where there are zero non-missing rows (hence they will be `NA`), whereas coursera asks you to use a `numeric(0)` vector (when added to a numeric vector disappears) ie see the difference between (`c(numeric(0),  -0.01895754, -0.14051254 )` and `c(NA,  -0.01895754, -0.14051254 )`)

Comment: Again, I really appreciate your help, user20650. I am going to try to figure out how to fix my function based on what you've said.